# A problem about the subgroup of an alternating group generated by two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I encountered the problem below.

Let $n$ be an odd integer, and denote by $H$ the subgroup of the alternating group $A_n$ generated by the following two elements: a cyclic permutation $(1\,\, 2\,\, \cdots \,\,n)$ and a 3-cycle $(a\,\,\, a+d\,\,\, a+2d)$, where $1\leq a< a+d<a+2d\leq n.$ Write $H$ as the direct product or semi-direct product of symmetric groups, alternating groups or cyclic groups. Compute the order of $H$.

I couldn't solve this problem but I tried something below.

Let $\tau=(1\,\, 2\,\, \cdots \,\,n)$ and $\sigma=(a\,\,\, a+d\,\,\, a+2d)$，then $\sigma^{-1}\tau^{-1}\sigma\tau=(a-1\,\,\, a+d-1\,\,\, a+2d-1)$. It means any element in the form $(x\,\,\, x+d\,\,\, x+2d)$ belongs to $H$. This is how far I can do.

I don't have the correct answer of this problem. How to solve this problem?

Comment: This looks hard! I have been trying some examples on the computer. If $d$ does not divide $n$ then you just get $A_n$. But it's more complicated when $d|n$. If $3|n$ and $\sigma = (1,4,7)$, then you get $A_{n/3} \wr A_3$. But when $d = n/3$ you seem to get a group of order $3^{n/3-1}n$.